# Rails new.html.erb is not recieving values or not passsing values to controller. from to get new values. following is my new.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

Rails `new.html.erb` is not recieving values or not passing values to the controller.  from to get new values.

following is my new.html.erb

```
def new
  @departmentdetail=DepartmentDetail.new
end

def create
  @departmentdetail=DepartmentDetail.new(department_param)
  if @departmentdetail.save
    redirect_to ('index')
  else
    redirect_to('new')
  end
end

def department_param
  params.require(:departmentdetail).permit(:departmentname, :departmentemail, :password)
end
```

```html
<%= form_for(@departmentdetail) do |f| %> 
  <table summary="Subject for fields"> 
    <tr> 
      <th> <%= f.label :departmentname %><br></th> 
      <td><%= f.text_field :departmentname %></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <th> <%= f.label :departmentemail %><br></th> 
      <td><%= f.text_field :departmentemail %></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <th> <%= f.label :password %><br></th> 
      <td><%= f.text_field :password %></td> 
    </tr>
  </table> 
  <%= f.submit("Create Department")%>
```

Comment: <%= form_for(@departmentdetail)  do |f| %>
  <table summary="Subject for fields">
    <tr>
      <th> <%= f.label :departmentname %><br></th>
      <td><%= f.text_field :departmentname %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> <%= f.label :departmentemail %><br></th>
      <td><%= f.text_field :departmentemail %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> <%= f.label :password %><br></th>
      <td><%= f.text_field :password %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  

    <%= f.submit("Create Department")%>

Answer (score 1):

You are not fully following Ruby on Rails naming conventions. When there is a class named `DepartmentDetail` then the variables and the keys in the strong params should be named with an underscore like this `department_detail`. Additionally, redirecting to `new` instead of just rendering `new` in the case of an error when saving will result in losing the current state:

I suggest changing your controller to:

```
def new
  @department_detail = DepartmentDetail.new
end

def create
  @department_detail = DepartmentDetail.new(department_detail_params)
  
  if @department_detail.save
    redirect_to :index
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def department_detail_params
  params.require(:department_detail).permit(:departmentname, :departmentemail, :password)
end
```

And your view to:

```
<%= form_for(@department_detail) do |f| %> 
  <table summary="Subject for fields"> 
    <tr> 
      <th> <%= f.label :departmentname %><br></th> 
      <td><%= f.text_field :departmentname %></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <th> <%= f.label :departmentemail %><br></th> 
      <td><%= f.text_field :departmentemail %></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <th> <%= f.label :password %><br></th> 
      <td><%= f.text_field :password %></td> 
    </tr>
  </table> 
  <%= f.submit("Create Department")%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user submits an invalid form you want to render - not redirect.

```
def create
  @departmentdetail = DepartmentDetail.new(department_param)
  if @departmentdetail.save
    redirect_to action: :index
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

This will render the `new.html.erb` view so that the user gets the form back but with messages about the validation errors.

On a technical level what you're actually doing here is rendering a response to the user sending a non-idempotent request - its a response custom tailored to that request. This is very different from the new action which is idempotent (the form looks the same for everyone).

If you redirect the user you'll lose all the user input and the validation messages.

Comment: Apart from the conceptual problem there are tons of style issues with this code - use the underscore convention `@department_detail`. Don't prefix your column names - use  `name` instead of `departmentname`. Do not put a space between the name of a method and the parens `redirect_to ('index')` which will cause a syntax error as soon as you add more then one parameter because you're actually doing `redirect_to(('index'))`. Do put spaces between `=` and the left and right values when doing assignment.